# Using vimdiff to find differences in a particular column

Tags: vim, diff, vimdiff

I have a very large csv file where every field is the same width (hence every line is the same width). I need to find the differences in a specific column.

When I open 2 files in vimdiff, most lines are marked as a diff, because there is a regularly changing datetime field (say, columns 10-15). This field is correctly coloured red for a diff. But I am interested in, say columns 50-60, in which there will only be a few diffs throughout the entire file.

My only solution so far is to delete the parts of the file that I don't care about `:%s/^.\{49}` but this is very laggy because the files are so big.

Is there a better solution without needing to modify the files?

Comment: I would rather prefer to `git --color-words --no-index -- file_a file_b`, it isn't related to `vim` though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would comparing specific fields be suitable?

```
vimdiff <(awk -F',' '{print $3}' a.csv) <(awk -F',' '{print $3}' b.csv)
```

Or, if you require a comparison among multiple fields:

```
vimdiff <(awk -F',' '{print $2","$3}' a.csv) <(awk -F',' '{print $2","$3}' b.csv)
```

Comment: This is working on my linux box, but the files I need to diff are on windows (using windows gvim). I have cygwin so I will look into setting up a bash script to open gvim for me. I'll accept your answer unless someone later provides a vim-only solution. Thanks!